# SQL Query - Cannot Find Parent Parts That Contain Two Specific Components

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I cannot find parent parts which contain 2 specific components which definitely exist.

I have tried the following query as attached. I know that the parents parent parts containing these components exist i.e. when I select all.

```
select *
from BomStructure
where  Component='322058-000000' and Component= '322123-301200'
```

I get no results.
[image]

Comment: The `Component` column can't be equal to two different values on the same row at the same time...

Comment: There must be a way to get the distinct parent part which contain both components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select * from BomStructure BS
where 
Component = '322058-000000' and
exists (select 1 from BomStructure where ParentPart = BS.ParentPart and Component = '322123-301200')
```

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The `Component` column can't be equal to two different values on the same row at the same time.

One way to do it is using a cte or a derived table to get the `ParentPart` that contains at least one record for each component, and join with the original table:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT ParentPart
    FROM BomStructure 
    WHERE Component IN('322058-000000', '322123-301200')
    GROUP BY ParentPart
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Component) = 2
)

SELECT BS.*
FROM BomStructure As BS
JOIN CTE 
    ON BS.ParentPart = CTE.ParentPart
```